# Disable "Stay signed in" for Google Inbox/Gmail

Tags: security, inbox-by-gmail, login, google-apps-for-work

Title says it all...

When I sign in to Google Inbox, the "Stay signed in" box is checked by default on the password screen. Sometimes I forget to uncheck it.

Is there a setting somewhere to disable it for good? (At least for my "Google Apps for Work" email?)

Answer (score 2):

Using either an Incognito window in the Chrome browser or Guest mode on a Chromebook will erase all cached data when you close the last tab. (Other browsers offer a "Private" browsing mode as well.) This includes your authorization or sign-in cookie. When using these modes it won't matter if "Stay signed in" is checked or not. You won't be logged in next time you open an Incognito window.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to disable this is by logging out of your email and logging back in. When you do log back in, do not check that box.

I don't know what browser you are using, but make sure that you take that account info off of your saved passwords list.

If all of the above won't work, I think your last resort would be deleting cookies/saved passwords (if saved passwords is even an option).

Answer (score -2):

You may want to use this add on:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/uncheck-stay-signed-in/

Comment: It'd be nice to explain that this is for Firefox only and exactly what it does. Also, if you have a vested interest in this add-on, you _must_ disclose that in your answer.